# Highstock theming range buttons

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts

So, I'm trying to theme the Highstock range buttons. Thing is, I can't find a detailed list of the available attributes i can use and how to use them. Right now I'm trying to get circular (not rounded corners, a full circle) buttons on this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QeDGC/4/

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                //fill: 'none',
                //stroke: 'none',
                //'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 15,
                height:26,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            inputBoxBorderColor: 'gray',
            inputBoxWidth: 120,
            inputBoxHeight: 18,
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'silver',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

The issue is, I don't know how to change the form of the button while keeping the text centered. I can change r and height until I get the look I want but the text wont be centered. If anyone can tell me what to change to center the text inside the buttons that would be great, but ideally I would love to have a link with a description of all the available SVG options I can use and what parameters do they take

Ty,

Axel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such option for translating text. Only you can set higher fontSize, but it's not great solution.

Workaround is to change y-offset for label only, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/QeDGC/5/

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this;
                $.each(chart.rangeSelector.buttons, function (i, button) {
                    var textStr = button.element.childNodes[1];
                    $(textStr).attr({
                        y: 20
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Well I guess it's still better than my dirty jQuery search and replace. Ty